# Monitor Internet activity

Tags: java

I want to desing java application that montior internet activity. Let consider I open different browser and that sending and receving data from internet. My application requirment is that to monitor that sending and receving packets. So my application working as services that generate log of internet surfing. How this posible in the java?

Comment: You are better off not using Java for this task.  In fact, WireShark is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [jNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com/). The site is full of [examples](http://jnetpcap.com/examples) and [tutorials](http://jnetpcap.com/tutorial).

Answer (score 6):

There are a few things you can do. If your end goal is to simply monitor the traffic, use an existing application like Ethereal or Wireshark.

Otherwise, if you want to write your own application, have a look the the Jpcap and/or JNetPcap libraries. They allow you to bind to network interfaces and sniff / analyse all the packets that pass through those interfaces.

Comment: when i am going to access the offical website i.e. http://jnetpcap.com/ following errors appear "Sorry, 115.186.117.102(My machine IP) has been banned." why this happening? any idea.

Comment: No idea, just went there and everything seems fine.